# Python Authentication Issue When Modularizing Tableau API

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have the following Python code that successfully authenticates and retrieves data using the Tableau API:

```
# Original Code
def get_all_client_users(client):
    client_users = []
    tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(
        os.getenv('tableau_username'), os.getenv('tableau_pass'), client)
    server = TSC.Server(os.getenv('tableau_server_url'),
                        use_server_version=True)
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        site_users, pagination_item = server.users.get()
        for user in site_users:
            client_users.append(user)
        return client_users
```

To make the code more modular, I decided to split the authentication process into a separate function as follows:

```
def get_all_client_users(client):
    client_users = []
    server = utils.get_tableau_server_controller(client)
    site_users, pagination_item = server.users.get()
    for user in site_users:
        client_users.append(user)
    return client_users
```

And in the utils.py module.

```
def get_tableau_server_controller(client):
    tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(os.getenv('tableau_username'), os.getenv('tableau_pass'), client)
    server = TSC.Server(os.getenv('tableau_server_url'), use_server_version=True)
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        return server
```

Issue:

After modularizing the code, the authentication process no longer works as expected.
Getting an exception: `Missing site ID. You must sign in first.`

I am not able to understand what can be different for the object when trying to use in the same block and accepting the object from a different function and using the same.

Feels like I am missing out on an important Python concept because of which I am not able to understand the issue.

Can someone guide me in identifying the issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

Run the with statement in get_all_client_users function.

```
def get_tableau_server_controller(client):
        tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(os.getenv('tableau_username'), os.getenv('tableau_pass'), client)
        server = TSC.Server(os.getenv('tableau_server_url'), use_server_version=True)
        return server
```

My understanding of the with statments is that it closes the resources right after processing them. the return statement ended the with statement.

```
def get_all_client_users(client):
    client_users = []
    server = utils.get_tableau_server_controller(client)
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        site_users, pagination_item = server.users.get()
        for user in site_users:
            client_users.append(user)
    return client_users
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Will try this

Answer (score 0):

It possibly an issue with you .env file. try specifying the path of the env file.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path

dotenv_path = Path('path/to/.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
```

so in the get_tableau_server_controller function.

```
def get_tableau_server_controller(client):
    tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(os.getenv('path/to/tableau_username.env'), 
    os.getenv('/path/to/tableau_pass.env'), client)
    server = TSC.Server(os.getenv('/path/to/tableau_server_url.env'), 
    use_server_version=True)
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        return server
```

Comment: I checked via debuggers. The value i get is same in both the modules

Comment: The other issue could be  how you used with.